# Ubuntu mirroring two screens

Tags: 14.04, video, display, configuration

I have two monitors: one build in display and oen oculus rift.
What I want to do is test my oculus rift by mirroring my screen across both devices, however both devices don' t share any resolutions,  just the 800 x 600 around 1/4 of what both their capacities are.

Is there a way to force the resolution of the oculus onto my screen and just cut off or blank the parts that have no info/are now outside of the screen?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try a utility called `Arandr`. I didn't test, of course, the Oculus Rift with this tool. But the program helped in cases when Ubuntu didn't allow achieving desired configuration by inbuilt stuff

`sudo apt-get install arandr`